# Loop through dates with PHP

Tags: php, date, loops

I am trying to loop through dates with PHP. Currently my code gets stuck in a loop repeating 110307. I need the date format to be in yymmdd. Here is what I was trying to use:

```
<?php
    $check_date = '100227';
    $end_date = '100324';

    while($check_date != $end_date){
        $check_date = date("ymd", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($check_date)));
        echo $check_date . '<br>';  
    }
?>
```

Comment: Then instead of `modify('+1 day');` for example, you can use the `->add` method.

Comment: @Itay Moav can you give me an example of what you mean by ->add

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtotime` interprets "100227" as the time 10:02:27 today, not 2010-02-27. So after the first step, `$check_date` (today) is "110307". At all subsequent steps "110307" is again interpreted as a time today, giving `$check_date` as "110307" again.

A neat trick for iterating dates is to take advantage of mktime's ability to normalize dates, something like this:

```
$date_arr = array(27,2,2010);
$end_date = "100324";
do {
    $check_date = gmdate('ymd', gmmktime(0,0,0,$date_arr[1],$date_arr[0]++,$date_arr[2]));
    echo $check_date."\n";
} while($end_date!=$check_date);
```

Comment: I didnt really use the code you gave me, but your reason for the problem helped me find a solution. Thanks for all the help

Comment: The explanation was the important part.

Answer (score 8):

Try using a unix timestamp and adding 86400 each time. That's gotta be faster than calling `strtotime()`. You can [lookup timestamp conversions online](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm).

```
<?php
    $check_date = 1267228800; // '2010-02-27';
    $end_date = 1269388800; // '2010-03-24';

    while($check_date != $end_date){
        $check_date += 86400;
        echo date("Ymd", $check_date) . '<br>';  
    }
?>
```

Comment: The date format needs to be left as yymmdd or atleast it will start as that and needs to be used in my code as that

Comment: You can do quick a conversion outside the loop, which is way cheaper (O(1)) than doing it every iteration (O(n)).

Comment: Never use 86400 seconds for a day due to daylight saving when day has 23 or 25 hours!

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I prefer to do it:

```
$startDate = new DateTime('20100227');
$endDate = new DateTime('20100324');

while ($startDate <= $endDate) {
  // your code here
  ...
  // go to the next day
  $startDate->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

I find this much cleaner personally, and it's nice not having to hard-code values like 84600.

Answer (score 2):

Here is part of a code I use, can probably be improved, depends on PHP version you use.

```
//usage
$Iterator=class Dates_DateIterator::factory('Daily',
                                           new Datetime('20100227'),
                                           new Datetime('20100324'));

foreach($Iterator as $i=>$day){
    var_dump($i);
    var_dump($day);
}


//code lib
abstract class Dates_DateIterator implements Iterator
{
    /**
     * Factory method, saves some code, also enable me to put everything in the same class 
     * as we use Autoload to load classes.
     */
    static public function factory($cycle,DateTime $DateI,DateTime $DateII){
        switch($cycle){
            case 'Daily':
                return new DaysIterator($DateI,$DateII);
            case 'Weekly':
                return new WeeksIterator($DateI,$DateII);
            case 'Monthly':
                return new MonthsIterator($DateI,$DateII);
            case 'Yearly':
                return new YearsIterator($DateI,$DateII);
            default:
                throw(new Exception('No valid cycle was chosen to iterate over'));
        }
    }
    /**
     * @var DateTime represents the start range.
     */
    public $FromDate;
    /**
     * @var DateTime represents the end range.
     */
    public $ToDate;
    /**
     * @var DateTime Current Date.
     */
    protected $CurrentDate;

    public function __construct(DateTime $DateI,DateTime $DateII)
    {
        if($DateII->format('U') > $DateI->format('U'))
        {
            $this->FromDate=$DateI;
            $this->ToDate=$DateII;
            $this->CurrentDate=$DateI;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->FromDate=$DateII;
            $this->ToDate=$DateI;
            $this->CurrentDate=$DateII;
        }
    }//EOF constructor

    /**
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getClonedCurrent(){
        return clone($this->CurrentDate);   
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->CurrentDate;
    }//EOF current

    public function currentDate()
    {
        return $this->CurrentDate->format('Ymd');
    }//EOF current

    public function rewind()
    {
        $this->CurrentDate=$this->FromDate;
    }//EOF rewind

    public function valid()
    {
        //Kill hours/minutes/seconds. If we are to add hours and minutes iterators, we will need to rethink this.
        return (floor($this->CurrentDate->format('U')/(3600*24)) <= floor($this->ToDate->format('U')/(3600*24)));
    }//EOF valid    
}//EOF CLASS  DateIterator









class DaysIterator extends SiTEL_Dates_DateIterator
{
    public function __construct(DateTime $DateI,DateTime $DateII)
    {
        parent::__construct($DateI,$DateII);
    }//EOF constructor

    public function next()
    {
        $this->CurrentDate->modify('+1 day');
    }//EOF next

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->CurrentDate->format('d');
    }//EOF key

}//EOD CLASS DaysIterator
```

Comment: Wow, that's super heavyweight.

Comment: @Paul Schreiber read the entire thing, it is part of a bigger framework/lib. It is heavy, you are right, as I need to use the same code exactly for different cycles (It is part of an event repeater calculator). But...It took me less time to put it here than the time it took you to write it :-)

Comment: I can see that. It seems like there's a big perf hit to import a framework and allocate/instantiate/destroy n objects.