# find missing date and then include in array

Tags: php

how to add $mydates (2019-04-01", "2019-04-08) include too in array ?

Give some suggestion please.

thanks

I referrer from here , but only find missing date
[Find missing dates in range (php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931841/find-missing-dates-in-range-php)

```
$myDates = array("2019-04-01", "2019-04-08");
$missingDates = array();

$dateStart = date_create("2019-04-01");
$dateEnd   = date_create("2019-04-".date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2019)));
$interval  = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period    = new DatePeriod($dateStart, $interval, $dateEnd);
foreach($period as $day) {
  $formatted = $day->format("Y-m-d");
  if(!in_array($formatted, $myDates)) $missingDates[] = $formatted;
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($missingDates);echo '</pre>';
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-04-02
    [1] => 2019-04-03
    [2] => 2019-04-04
    [3] => 2019-04-05
    [4] => 2019-04-06
    [5] => 2019-04-07
    [6] => 2019-04-09
    [7] => 2019-04-10
    [8] => 2019-04-11
    [9] => 2019-04-12
    [10] => 2019-04-13
    [11] => 2019-04-14
    [12] => 2019-04-15
    [13] => 2019-04-16
    [14] => 2019-04-17
    [15] => 2019-04-18
    [16] => 2019-04-19
    [17] => 2019-04-20
    [18] => 2019-04-21
    [19] => 2019-04-22
    [20] => 2019-04-23
    [21] => 2019-04-24
    [22] => 2019-04-25
    [23] => 2019-04-26
    [24] => 2019-04-27
    [25] => 2019-04-28
    [26] => 2019-04-29
    [27] => 2019-04-30
)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `date_create("2019-04-".date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2019)));`?

Comment: It does not work as expected if the current month has 30 days. Check this out: https://3v4l.org/B7dWM

Comment: Do not mix `DateTime` with `mktime()`, `date()` and other old [date & time functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php). Use only [`DateTime` and the related classes](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php); they are easier to use and they handle the timezones properly (what the old date & time functions do not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want as the output, but maybe some of these will give you some Ideas.

Like this for your code:

```
$missingDates = array("2019-04-01", "2019-04-08");

$dateStart = date_create("2019-04-01");
$dateEnd   = date_create("2019-04-".date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2019)));
$interval  = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period    = new DatePeriod($dateStart, $interval, $dateEnd);
foreach($period as $day) {
  $formatted = $day->format("Y-m-d");
  if(!in_array($formatted, $missingDates)) $missingDates[] = $formatted;
}

sort($missingDates);

echo '<pre>';print_r($missingDates);echo '</pre>';
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-04-01
    [1] => 2019-04-02
    [2] => 2019-04-03
    [3] => 2019-04-04
    [4] => 2019-04-05
    [5] => 2019-04-06
    [6] => 2019-04-07
    [7] => 2019-04-08
    [8] => 2019-04-09
    [9] => 2019-04-10
    [10] => 2019-04-11
    [11] => 2019-04-12
    [12] => 2019-04-13
    [13] => 2019-04-14
    [14] => 2019-04-15
    [15] => 2019-04-16
    [16] => 2019-04-17
    [17] => 2019-04-18
    [18] => 2019-04-19
    [19] => 2019-04-20
    [20] => 2019-04-21
    [21] => 2019-04-22
    [22] => 2019-04-23
    [23] => 2019-04-24
    [24] => 2019-04-25
    [25] => 2019-04-26
    [26] => 2019-04-27
    [27] => 2019-04-28
    [28] => 2019-04-29
    [29] => 2019-04-30
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae4b03ae67fed0e853f4d374e1006f8bcf1efdc0)

One note here is this `2019` is probably going to cause you some issues in `2020`

```
$dateEnd   = date_create("2019-04-".date("t", mktime(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2019)));
```

You can't really fix this, because by the time you do it's preferable to use a date time for that, as I do below.  You'll wind up turning the end date into a date time object, so you can get the year `(new DateTime("2019-04-08"))->format('Y')` at which point you might as well just use one of the options below. You cannot simply use the `$dateStart` object because the `$dateEnd` could be in next year depending on what you actually want.

**All the days of this month**

The above basically just gives you all the days of the month which you could do this way:

```
function getDaysOfMonth($date){
    $dateStart = (new DateTime($date))->modify('first day of this month'); 
    $dateEnd = (new DateTime($date))->modify('first day of next month');
    $interval  = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $period    = new DatePeriod($dateStart, $interval, $dateEnd);
    $formatted = [];

    foreach($period as $day) $formatted[] = $day->format("Y-m-d");
    return $formatted;
}

print_r(getDaysOfMonth('2019-04-10'));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-04-01
    [1] => 2019-04-02
    [2] => 2019-04-03
    [3] => 2019-04-04
    [4] => 2019-04-05
    [5] => 2019-04-06
    [6] => 2019-04-07
    [7] => 2019-04-08
    [8] => 2019-04-09
    [9] => 2019-04-10
    [10] => 2019-04-11
    [11] => 2019-04-12
    [12] => 2019-04-13
    [13] => 2019-04-14
    [14] => 2019-04-15
    [15] => 2019-04-16
    [16] => 2019-04-17
    [17] => 2019-04-18
    [18] => 2019-04-19
    [19] => 2019-04-20
    [20] => 2019-04-21
    [21] => 2019-04-22
    [22] => 2019-04-23
    [23] => 2019-04-24
    [24] => 2019-04-25
    [25] => 2019-04-26
    [26] => 2019-04-27
    [27] => 2019-04-28
    [28] => 2019-04-29
    [29] => 2019-04-30
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94852e24206b40bfe734318ab1e801d975c2c2e5)

**Remaining days of the month**

Just change this line in the above:

```
 $dateStart = (new DateTime($date))->modify('first day of this month');
```

To

```
 $dateStart = new DateTime($date);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-04-10
    [1] => 2019-04-11
    [2] => 2019-04-12
    [3] => 2019-04-13
    [4] => 2019-04-14
    [5] => 2019-04-15
    [6] => 2019-04-16
    [7] => 2019-04-17
    [8] => 2019-04-18
    [9] => 2019-04-19
    [10] => 2019-04-20
    [11] => 2019-04-21
    [12] => 2019-04-22
    [13] => 2019-04-23
    [14] => 2019-04-24
    [15] => 2019-04-25
    [16] => 2019-04-26
    [17] => 2019-04-27
    [18] => 2019-04-28
    [19] => 2019-04-29
    [20] => 2019-04-30
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a0c16c7f99ba802ea25f6a1433fd37379b68d60)

**Start to End (inclusive)**

This gives you all the days, but if you only want from your first to your second you can use this:

```
function getDays($dateStart,$dateEnd){

    $dateStart = new DateTime($dateStart); 
    $dateEnd = (new DateTime($dateEnd))->modify('+1 day'); 
    $interval  = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $period    = new DatePeriod($dateStart, $interval, $dateEnd);
    $formatted = [];

    foreach($period as $day) $formatted[] = $day->format("Y-m-d");



    return $formatted;
}

print_r(getDays('2019-04-01', '2019-04-08'));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2019-04-01
    [1] => 2019-04-02
    [2] => 2019-04-03
    [3] => 2019-04-04
    [4] => 2019-04-05
    [5] => 2019-04-06
    [6] => 2019-04-07
    [7] => 2019-04-08
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68a9937a4ef3ce514473f7939efa2874d8d0889d)

Comment: thank you for the input, which I want in the first point,
I want to get the missing date in the specified month based on the dropdown menu.